# will_paginate renders current page outside of pagination div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate in my rails project and I get this behavior, the current page number, is outside of the numbers. Here is an image.

[image: will_paginate]

And here is the html code generated by will_paginate

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="pagination">
        <a class="previous_page" rel="prev start" href="/offers?page=1">← Previous</a> 
        <a rel="prev start" href="/offers?page=1">1</a>
        <em class="current">2</em> 
        <span class="next_page disabled">Next →</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone can help me with this issues, please???

---

Rails code:

```
def index
    @offers = Offer.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Comment: That's a CSS issue. Post the code you use for styling pagination please.

Comment: Well I'm using twitter bootstrap, but I didn't define any css to the will_paginate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap, check out this gem:

https://github.com/yrgoldteeth/bootstrap-will_paginate

The markup from `will_paginate` is a bit different from the bootstrap one - this gem adjusts it to work with bootstrap.